# How to sound-proof a loud room

Tags: sound-proofing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I temporarily soundproof my apartment ceiling?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4534/how-can-i-temporarily-soundproof-my-apartment-ceiling)

I often hold parties with music at my house and would like to do a courtesy to the neighbors by soundproofing my walls. Their house is about 100' away.

Is there a way I could block or dampen the sound going out, preferably a non-permanent solution? I have thought of acoustic foam panels, sound absorption sheets, even a treeline between our houses, but as I have never done this sort of thing before, would like the community's input.

Thanks

Comment: At 100' away, I wonder if they can hear all of the music or if it is only the bass that is a problem? Bass, being low frequency, tends to be very difficult to block